# How to import a class inside one package into another class in a different package?

Tags: java

I have to solve an exercise related to java packages. The hierarchy and the package names are already created with the question and cannot be changed.

```
Project
|__src
    |__main
        |__java
             |__code
             |   |__numbers
             |          |__Numberfinder.java
             |__com
                 |__keith
                      |__Main.java
```

I have to use Numberfinder class in Main.java. So in Main.java I wrote:

in Main.java -

`import java.code.numbers.Numberfinder`

But this was highlighted in red and showed error as Numberfinder not found.

I also tried : `import code.numbers.Numberfinder` in Main.java

But it did'nt work either.

Kindly suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import code.numbers.Numberfinder;` is the correct import. If you are having issues with that you need to mark `src/main/java` as the source directory